# How to check spell different languages at the same time?

Tags: language-support

I went to System Preferences > Language Support. My active languages for menus and windows are English, German and Spanish. (Spanish as a first choice). But when I write in english or german I get the red underline. How to avoid this and get my applications to accept all three languages?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think the easiest way would be to simply combine all the dictionaries into one file . cat english.dict german.dict >> spanish.dict

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Do I just type that in a terminal?

Comment: How about changing the language used for spellchecking to the language you currently use? Or disable spellchecking, if you just want to get rid of the red underlines.

Comment: no, you have to find the dictionary

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson It would be a bit boring to change that feature each couple of hours. Also I'm learning german so it would be nice to get a warning when I write something wrong.

Comment: I see. Well, @bodhi.zazen's idea might be possible, but I don't think it's easily accomplished.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I found them in usr/share/dict I typed cat english.... >> gerspanglish. But now I cannot select it

Comment: yes, back up the dictionaries first

Comment: @bodhi.zazen do you mean like making a copy of them?

Comment: There are other kinds of spellchecking dictionaries in e.g. `/usr/share/hunspell`.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I tried saving all the dictionaries to a single one, but still only spanish is recognised as the one to check spelling

Comment: This approach would probably need a tutorial. I'm not the one who is going to write it. ;) Sorry.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: Let me add one thing: The _Language Support_ tool primarily controls the display language, i.e. the language in which menus and messages are displayed. Spellchecking can be controlled separately in respective application, e.g. _LibreOffice_.